# Powershell - message sent outside the organization

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I would like to have emails sent externally but only if there are more than 2 external recipients.

Get-MessageTrace -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) -EndDate (Get-Date) -Status Delivered | Where-Object {$*.RecipientAddress -notmatch "@myorganisation.fr" -and $*.RecipientAddress -notmatch "@toto.fr"}

I have all outgoing emails, even those with only 1 recipient :( :(

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does `Get-MessageTrace` output separate objects per recipient? Eg. for a message sent to 3 external recipients, do you get 3 separate rows of output?

Comment: yes 3 separate lines

Answer (score 1):

Once you've filtered out internal recipients, use `Group-Object` to group the traces by Message ID and then filter out groups with just 1 element:

```
Get-MessageTrace -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) -EndDate (Get-Date) -Status Delivered | Where-Object {
  $.RecipientAddress -notmatch "@myorganisation.fr" -and $.RecipientAddress -notmatch "@toto.fr"
} |Group-Object MessageId |Where-Object Count -gt 1 |Select-Object Name,@{Name='Recipients';Expression = {$_.Group |ForEach-Object RecipientAddress}}
```

This should give you 1 output object per message, with the message id and external recipients attached to each